# ASP.NET Web Forms and separation of concerns

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I will be leading a team to create a complex manufacturing web app in ASP.NET (web forms) soon, and previously our business logic would be in the same project, or even worse, in the code behind of the page.

I understand that seperation of concerns is important, and makes testing much easier (testing has always been a problem of ours), so this is the direction we want to go in.

I'm a bit confused about how this can be implemented however - we use a lot of RadGrid's etc which we bind to SqlDataSources. How would things like these work with all of the business logic in another project?

Comment: SqlDataSources are the arch-enemies of business logic isolation. Can't you replace than by any kind of object-based data-source? The business logic layer should be responsible for retrieving these objects.

Comment: SqlDataSource is very bad..

Answer (score 2):

My advices are:

- If you can, forget about SqlDataSources. If you are using SqlDataSources, you will still be able to have some business rules isolation, but for data-centric applications, most of the business rules are related to editing and retrieving data. The best kind of data-sources are simple IEnumerables. Most Grid controls will support it. Your business rules should retrieve simple C# objects which are bound to the Grid controls. ObjectDataSource is a good choice as well.
- Use ASP.NET MVC instead of ASP.NET WebForms if you can. The advantage in terms of testability and separation of concerns is huge. That's why this technology has been created. As you are starting a new project, I'd strongly recommend it. In fact, ASP.NET MVC is all about having the Controller layer passing objects to the View, which can display them.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to keep your webforms, but use the MVP pattern. We found that it had a much lower barrier of entry for new or junior developers as it's just simple c# (no need to learn Razor or the conventions of MVC), and we found that 90% of the development could be done by devs who knew absolutely nothing about web development (we basically abstracted usage of anything web-related, like the user or Profile, to make the business code more reusable).

You would have to do away with the `SqlDataSource`s, but I agree with everyone else that those are evil as well. In our implementation, the data would be retrieved from the database and wrapped in a POCO DTO, passed to the view as an IEnumerable, then databound in the page's code-behind.

Another benefit of MVP in the enterprise world is its resilience to change. Since the view is dumb as possible, it's very simple to switch it out. You could use the same Models and Presenters, and have Views in Winforms, Silverlight, Webforms, and a console app simultaneously. The implementation of the view has no bearing on the Presenter or Model.

MVC is the new hotness, but having used both MVC and MVP, for large enterprise webapps where maintainability and reliability is key, I'd recommend MVP.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ObjectDataSource instead of SqlDataSource to utilize classes in other projects (i.e. another layer), but you're still going to be fighting an uphill battle using Web Forms.

If separation of concerns and testability are significant concerns, I would highly recommend using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: I'd love to use MVC, but our app is likely to be very complex and we love using the Telerik AJAX library and the relatively sparse library of third party controls for MVC is a problem

Comment: @Chris Telerik for MVC is awesome (Kendo UI now). Test it. Really.. You will appreciate it.